# Django not dispatching the request to correct view function

Tags: ajax, django

I am new to Django. And I am building an ecommerce  website.

I have these 2 urls.

```
  path('', views.cart, name='cart'),
  path('delete/<int:order_id>', views.cart, name='remove')
```

These are 2 functions in my views

```
def cart(request):

def remove(request, order_id):
```

When ever I try to make request to the remove view it gives me this error.

```
   TypeError: cart() got an unexpected keyword argument 'order_id'

   http://localhost:8000/cart/delete/96
```

What I understand from this is that it is calling the cart method instead of remove.

The cart method is working fine.

I am calling this remove method with Ajax.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: `delete/${order_id}`,
  success: function(){
  console.log("helloo");
}});
```

I think i am missing some thing very basic here.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: In both urls you have been write views.cart, in the second one is views.remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo. The second URL calls the view `cart` instead of `remove`.

Change the urls.py as follow:

```py
  path('', views.cart, name='cart'),
  path('delete/<int:order_id>', views.remove, name='remove')
```